# Do I need transit visa for Amsterdam?

Tags: visas, transit, indian-citizens, transit-visas, ams

[image]

I am an Indian citizen going to the UK in June on visitor visa, multiple entry valid until October. On my return journey, I have a layover of 12 hours and 15 minutes, and I also have to change planes from KLM to Jet Airways. Do I need a transit visa? Is there any option that I can get visa for 12 hours (short stay visa or transit visa) at the Amsterdam airport itself?

Answer (score 0):

As stated by [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=in&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=00&TR=nl&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), the database used by airlines:

> Visa required, **except** for Holders of onward tickets transiting by the same or first connecting aircraft:

So no, you do **not** Need a visa